# vertical border in longtable + booktabs + repeating table header

Tags: tables, longtable, booktabs

This seems to be a bug in booktabs + longtable when there are repeating header rows. I got an error report on this from the r package kableExtra. 
https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/377

This seems to be a universal bug but my limited latex knowledge can't tell me how to solve this. Could someone give me some hint on if this bug is solvable?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|>{}r|>{}r|>{}rrl}
\caption{\label{tab:}repeat header}\\
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{repeat header \textit{(continued)}}\\
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\midrule
\endhead
\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.7 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.4 & 3.9 & 1.7 & 0.4 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.4 & 1.4 & 0.3 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.4 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.4 & 2.9 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.1 & setosa\\

5.4 & 3.7 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.8 & 3.4 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.8 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.1 & setosa\\
4.3 & 3.0 & 1.1 & 0.1 & setosa\\
5.8 & 4.0 & 1.2 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.7 & 4.4 & 1.5 & 0.4 & setosa\\
5.4 & 3.9 & 1.3 & 0.4 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.3 & setosa\\
5.7 & 3.8 & 1.7 & 0.3 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.8 & 1.5 & 0.3 & setosa\\

5.4 & 3.4 & 1.7 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.7 & 1.5 & 0.4 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.6 & 1.0 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.3 & 1.7 & 0.5 & setosa\\
4.8 & 3.4 & 1.9 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.0 & 3.0 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.4 & 1.6 & 0.4 & setosa\\
5.2 & 3.5 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.2 & 3.4 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.7 & 3.2 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\

4.8 & 3.1 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.4 & 3.4 & 1.5 & 0.4 & setosa\\
5.2 & 4.1 & 1.5 & 0.1 & setosa\\
5.5 & 4.2 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.0 & 3.2 & 1.2 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.5 & 3.5 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.1 & setosa\\
4.4 & 3.0 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.4 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.0 & 3.5 & 1.3 & 0.3 & setosa\\
4.5 & 2.3 & 1.3 & 0.3 & setosa\\
4.4 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.5 & 1.6 & 0.6 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.8 & 1.9 & 0.4 & setosa\\

4.8 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.3 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.8 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.2 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.3 & 3.7 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.3 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\

6.7 & 3.0 & 5.2 & 2.3 & virginica\\
6.3 & 2.5 & 5.0 & 1.9 & virginica\\
6.5 & 3.0 & 5.2 & 2.0 & virginica\\
6.2 & 3.4 & 5.4 & 2.3 & virginica\\
5.9 & 3.0 & 5.1 & 1.8 & virginica\\*
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: @leandriis Apparently this is not a booktab issue. I will update the question.

Comment: what did you want `\ \endfoot` to do if not generate that row?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I looked into the history of my code https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/commit/44f6c49393f4d167790135e871afe3498d66a243 It seems that I was only trying to let \endfoot start with a newline but accidentally put in an extra \... Somehow this \ has no effect on normal tables so it was not brought up until someone found it out today.

Comment: the `\ ` would have exactly the same effect in a tabular, if you end a tabular with `\\ \  \end{tabular}` then there will be a spurious line at the bottom and (just) the leftmost vertical rule will be extended. But no matter, I was just checking that the answer of "delete that" actually did what you need rather than just making the error message go away.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. That's good to learn! I was trying to recall but couldn't remember the reason why the `\ ` was there. Anyway, I have a few test cases. I compared the results. It seems that removing this `\ ` doesn't affect them at all except fixing this bug. So I guess we are good. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you describe is caused by the `\` in line 19. If you comment it out, the left vertical lines are no longer too long.

Apart from that, I'd recommend against using `booktabs`' horizontal rules with vertical lines. For more information on this see the `booktabs` documentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|>{}r|>{}r|>{}rrl}
\caption{\label{tab:}repeat header}\\
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{repeat header \textit{(continued)}}\\
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\midrule
\endhead
%\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.7 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.4 & 3.9 & 1.7 & 0.4 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.4 & 1.4 & 0.3 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.4 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.4 & 2.9 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.1 & setosa\\

5.4 & 3.7 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.8 & 3.4 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.8 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.1 & setosa\\
4.3 & 3.0 & 1.1 & 0.1 & setosa\\
5.8 & 4.0 & 1.2 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.7 & 4.4 & 1.5 & 0.4 & setosa\\
5.4 & 3.9 & 1.3 & 0.4 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.3 & setosa\\
5.7 & 3.8 & 1.7 & 0.3 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.8 & 1.5 & 0.3 & setosa\\

5.4 & 3.4 & 1.7 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.7 & 1.5 & 0.4 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.6 & 1.0 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.3 & 1.7 & 0.5 & setosa\\
4.8 & 3.4 & 1.9 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.0 & 3.0 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.4 & 1.6 & 0.4 & setosa\\
5.2 & 3.5 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.2 & 3.4 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.7 & 3.2 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\

4.8 & 3.1 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.4 & 3.4 & 1.5 & 0.4 & setosa\\
5.2 & 4.1 & 1.5 & 0.1 & setosa\\
5.5 & 4.2 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.0 & 3.2 & 1.2 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.5 & 3.5 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.1 & setosa\\
4.4 & 3.0 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.4 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\

5.0 & 3.5 & 1.3 & 0.3 & setosa\\
4.5 & 2.3 & 1.3 & 0.3 & setosa\\
4.4 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.5 & 1.6 & 0.6 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.8 & 1.9 & 0.4 & setosa\\

4.8 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.3 & setosa\\
5.1 & 3.8 & 1.6 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.2 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.3 & 3.7 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.3 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\

6.7 & 3.0 & 5.2 & 2.3 & virginica\\
6.3 & 2.5 & 5.0 & 1.9 & virginica\\
6.5 & 3.0 & 5.2 & 2.0 & virginica\\
6.2 & 3.4 & 5.4 & 2.3 & virginica\\
5.9 & 3.0 & 5.1 & 1.8 & virginica\\*
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Yeah, I agree. The little gaps around midrule and toprule don't look that great. I will accept as answer once the cool down is over.